# Script to Specify the FTP File Path

Tags: file, upload, path, ftp

Anyone know if I can specify the file path for an FTP upload or script it if there isnt an FTP option to do this in a program? I'm using ScreenPresso Screenshot Software but the FTP Upload doesnt have an option to send it to a certain file path but there is a Scripting option that the program supports. I have no idea what coding is used. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you specify your ftp address include the subfolders as well as

```
ftp://foo/bar/baz/qux
```

Other than that you could try asking their support.

Comment: Hmm...I thought about that but wasn't sure if it would work. Is that the same has the host that it's being uploaded too then or no? I know html and css and a little bit of javascript but beyond that I'm not too certain at the moment.

Comment: Yeah. Try yourFTProot/directory/you/want.. :D sorry if it wasnt clear first time round.Im sleep deprived